# Ошибка при записывании прерываний в IVT в Assembler

Tags: ассемблер

Появился такой вопрос: у меня есть такой код (он ниже), в котором я хочу зарегестрировать все свободные для записи прерывания (от 0x20 до 0xff), но когда я пытаюсь это сделать, моя виртуальная машина крашится. Буду рад, если поможете. Код написан на GNU Assembler. А сам код является загрузчиком (bootloader).

`register_interrupts:
   cli
   xorw %ax, %ax
   movw %ax, %es
   movw $MorphBootloader_INT20, %es:0x80
   movw %cs, %es:0x82
   .....
   movw $MorphBootloader_INTFF, %es:0x3fc
   movw %cs, %es:0x3fe
   sti
 MorphBootloader_INT20:
   ...
   iret
 .....
 MorphBootloader_INTFF:
   ...
   iret`

Comment: А зачем вы это делаете ? В системе есть много прерываний с номерами > 0x20 которые необходимы для работы bios или еще чего нибудь важного. Например после 0x70 есть обработчики прерываний от некоторых устройств, которые надо правильно обрабатывать. А некоторые вектора содержат вообще не адреса обработчиков а адреса структур bios. Так что вы пробуйте для начала небольшими участками их перехватывать и смотрите на чем конкретно крашится

Comment: Спасибо, попробую

Comment: Ещё заметил, если я регистрирую прерывания от 0x20 до 0x4f, то виртуальная машина не крашится, но прерывания не работают...

Comment: А если регестрирую от 0x20 до 0x48, то мои прерывания не работают, а прерывания BIOS, работают (проверял на 0x10)

Comment: Что значит "прерывания не работают" ? Вы их явно вызываете int, внутри стоит отладочная печать и она ничего не выводит ?

Comment: Это значит, что если например я вызову прерывание 0x10 (вывести символ), то ничего не произойдёт.

Comment: Определяйте после перехвата какого прерывания это начинается. Видимо вы задеваете какие то вектора, которые нужны для работы bios

Comment: Методом перебора я узнал (брал участки от 0x20 до 0x2f, от 0x30 до 0x3f и т.д.) что по отдельности такие участки отлично работают, но все вместе - нет.

Comment: а это в какой части загрузчика ? Может когда вы выполняете много действий код становится по размеру больше, чем вы загружаете ?

Comment: Первый сегмент (загрузочный (который 512 байт)) - содержит у меня только переход ко второму сегменту, а во втором сегменте - этот код.

Comment: Могу попытаться выложить его.

Comment: [https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ADAAVeooKmM7jiDhEK-_ZYb10q-x6fMK/view?usp=sharing]

Comment: Как я понял вы дочитываете 2 сектора как бы в то же место где изначально собран код. 2 сектора в принципе должно хватить если не раскоментаривать все строки. У вас одних только iret 222 байта. В общем всегда убеждайтесь что весь размер скомпилированного файла не превышает 512*3.

Comment: А если я раскоментирую, то сколько примерно мне секторов пригодится?

Comment: А теперь самое главное: bios выделяет загрузчику стек размером 512 байт сразу после прочитанного первого сектора. Вы в эту область читаете свое продолжение и любые прерывания во время работы могут затирать часть вашего кода, потому что пишут туда стек ... Правда вы делаете ss=0 после чего стек переезжает куда то в область таблицы прерываний, что еще хуже. Так что разберитесь где будете держать стек (ss:sp)

Comment: И что значит "У одних только iret 222 байта"? Я смотрел скомпилированный файл, и там только 1 байт  iret

Comment: инструкция iret занимает 1 байт. у вас там 222 iret написано, если не ошибаюсь. А сколько секторов читать оценивайте сами: `(размер_скомпилированного_файла - 512)/512` с округлением вверх

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена. Проблема была в том, что нужно было поделить мой код на сегменты, а я все функции во второй сегмент записал. В итоге я разбил весь код на 14 сегментов (вообще 15), и эти 14 сегментов заполнены регистрированием прерываний в вектор. Спасибо большое за помощь пользователю Mike.